# VB.net Drag SINGLE Outlook msg and drop on form

Tags: vb.net, drag-and-drop, outlook

I have code working for me to be able to drag and drop outlook items onto my form (label) but I want to make sure only ONE file is dropped. So how can I properly code this to disallow multiple files from outlook and to prompt the user for only one file?

```
Private Sub Label1_DragDrop(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs) Handles Label1.DragDrop
        lblFile.Text = String.Empty
        Try

            If e.Data.GetDataPresent("FileGroupDescriptor") Then
                'supports a drop of a Outlook message

                'Dim objMI As Object - if you want to do late-binding
                Dim objMI As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem

                For Each objMI In objOL.ActiveExplorer.Selection()
                    'hardcode a destination path for testing
                    Dim strFile As String = _
                                IO.Path.Combine("c:\temp", _
                                                (objMI.Subject + ".msg").Replace(":", ""))
                    lblFile.Text += strFile + Environment.NewLine
                    objMI.SaveAs(strFile)
                Next
            End If
            lblFormat.Text = String.Empty
            IO.File.Delete(lblFile.Text)
        Catch ex As Exception
            lblFile.Text = "An error occured in the drop event" + Environment.NewLine + ex.ToString
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: `if objoL.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count >1 then`

Comment: Perfect. Not sure how to answer a comment though.

Comment: There is no way to answer a comment, but I didn't have the time to type it all out.  I'll add an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the documentation, the [`Application.ActiveExplorer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/Ff870017.aspx) method returns an [`Explorer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff864246.aspx) object.  The [`Selection()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff861267.aspx) property of the `Explorer` object returns a [`Collection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yb7y698k(v=vs.90).aspx) object.

A `Collection` is an enumerable object, so it has a property called `.Count` which will tell you how many items it holds. You can use this property to check if a selection contains more than one item like so:

```
if objoL.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count >1 then
```